# Amazon Redshift Load Optimization

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm currently migrating a DB containing mostly web analytics data to Redshift from Postgresql. I'm having trouble optimizing the load process. I'm seeking feedback on my schema and the general approach I'm using.

Here's a small sample of the schema that illustrates the problem I'm having:

```
CREATE TABLE dim_browser (
    browser_key integer IDENTITY(-2,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    browser_name varchar(40) DEFAULT 'Unknown'::text NOT NULL,
    version varchar(30) DEFAULT 'Unknown'::text NOT NULL,
    row_created_at timestamp DEFAULT getdate(),
    UNIQUE(browser_name, version)
);

CREATE TABLE fact_visit (
    visit_key integer IDENTITY(-2,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    visit_uuid char(36) NOT NULL UNIQUE, -- the natural key
    universal_start_date_key integer DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL REFERENCES dim_date,
    universal_start_time_key integer DEFAULT -1 NOT NULL REFERENCES dim_time,
    universal_start_timestamp timestamp DEFAULT '1900-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp NOT NULL,
    customer_id bigint NOT NULL,
    visitor_key integer NOT NULL REFERENCES dim_visitor,
    entry_web_page_key integer NOT NULL REFERENCES dim_web_page,
    browser_key integer DEFAULT -1 NOT NULL REFERENCES dim_browser,
    device_key integer DEFAULT -1 NOT NULL REFERENCES dim_device,
    operating_system_key integer DEFAULT -1 NOT NULL REFERENCES dim_operating_system,
    row_created_at timestamp DEFAULT getdate()
  DISTKEY(customer_id)
  SORTKEY(universal_start_date_key);
```

All the data in the DW comes off a Kinesis stream and is written to CSVs.
The CSVs are loaded into Kinesis as follows (using fact_visit as an example):

- create a temp table `fact_visit_load` that contains the same columns as `fact_visit`, excluding the surrogate key/identity column, and having additional columns as required for identifying any foreign keys. For instance, `fact_visit_load` has columns `browser_name` and `browser_version`, allowing us to uniquely identify a `dim_browser` record and get its `browser_key`. The CSVs have this same schema.
- copy the csv into the temp table. All foreign key referencing columns (like `browser_key`) are initially null.
- delete any duplicates from the temp table. Duplicates are identified by natural key; for `fact_visit`, records with matching `visit_uuid` values are deduplicated.
- delete from the temp table any records that already appear in the main table, again by natural key. `delete from fact_visit_load where visit_uuid in (select visit_uuid from fact_visit)`
- update all foreign keys. This involves several queries like `update fact_visit_load set browser_key = select browser_key from dim_browser b where b.browser_name = fact_visit.browser_key and b.version = fact_visit.browser_version`. There are some optimizations in place here, like getting multiple fks in the same query where possible.
- Insert into the main table from the temp table

This load process is ordered so that tables that depend on other tables (eg fact_visit's dependency on dim_browser) are loaded after the tables they depend upon. This ensures the foreign key lookups work.

The two bottlenecks are the updates to set the foreign keys and the deduplication by natural key against the main table.

So my questions are:

- Regarding the schema, is it a bad idea to use surrogate keys like this? Should I always use natural keys as primary keys instead? Would this affect the performance of joins, since I'd be using md5 hash columns or uuids for all primary keys?
- Is this process reasonable, or am I fighting against Redshift if I load data this way?
- If the schema and process are good, what can I do to improve load times?

Comment: i don't quite know where to start as this is a huge question - well worded and explain though! I guess you know the most important part to get right is the sortkey and dist key. so 2 questions 1) why are you using customer_id as distkey? 2) Im sure there are a lot of things that could be changed but what is your main challenge here? is it taking too long to load? can you give some table sizes / timings?

Comment: also - is there some reason why you can't fundamentally change your dw design? make the tables wider etc? e.g. a lot of reporting is relying on the format?

Comment: Customer_id is the dist key because I expected the least skew with that choice. Note however that I'm only using one node (dense storage), so the dist key isn't relevant here. (Correct me if I'm wrong on that though.) The main challenge is that loads currently take about 1.5hours, and seem to be getting slower as the database grows. The largest and slowest to load table has 586,164,861 rows and takes about 20 minutes to load. I am open to fundamentally changing the db design, but would appreciate guidance as to what those changes should be or links explaining why they're necessary :)

Comment: you are wrong on the dist key - its critical for single node too. the question is - will most queries look at all customer ids, or just 1. if  just 1 then its a very bad dist key.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. It looks like I have a few tables with bad dist keys that I will need to fix. Aside from those, do you have any suggestions about the three questions at the bottom of my original post?

Comment: "The largest and slowest to load table has 586,164,861 rows and takes about 20 minutes to load" - are you loading the entire table every time?

Comment: No, each batch just loads up new records from the last hour.